# Getting "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when using elif

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm getting the following error when I run the following program

```
File "main.py", line 14
    elif age >= 45 and <= 55:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the code that I wrote

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))


if height >= 120:
  print("You can ride the rollercoaster!")
  age = int(input("What is your age? "))
  if age < 12:
      bill = 5
      print("Child tickets are $5.")
  elif age <= 18:
      bill = 7
      print("Youth tickets are $7.")
  elif age >= 45 and <= 55:
      bill = 0
      print("Everything is going to be okay! Have a free ride on us <3.")
```

I was under the impression that this line was written properly

```
elif age >= 45 and <= 55:
```

Comment: Try `elif age >= 45 and age <= 55:`

Comment: omg thank you!! I've been sitting here for a whole day thinking I should just give up lmbo <3

Comment: @iScripters `45 <= age <= 55`

Answer (score 0):

You can use brackets to ensure that there are two statements in one line and they do not conflict with them. Here is my answer. you just need to modify the line or you can copy paste it.

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
    height = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))
    
    
    if height >= 120:
      print("You can ride the rollercoaster!")
      age = int(input("What is your age? "))
      if age < 12:
          bill = 5
          print("Child tickets are $5.")
      elif age <= 18:
          bill = 7
          print("Youth tickets are $7.")
      elif (age >= 45) and (age <= 55):
          bill = 0
          print("Everything is going to be okay! Have a free ride on us <3.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your elif statement from

> elif age >=45 and <=55

To

> elif age>=45 and age<=55

You should write the conditions completely

Answer (score -1):

In python you can say:

```
elif 45 >= age <= 55:
    pass
```

This syntax makes your intent clear and is a lot easier to read.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).